# Installing gdata Python package on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, contacts, gdata

First, a disclaimer that I am new to Python (I come from Ruby). I'm trying to integrate Google Contacts API into my Heroku Python app. Seem to having a hard time figuring out how to push the gdata package (https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to Heroku. This is the Heroku error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-07-03T09:03:58.205264+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "message.py", line 16, in <module>
2014-07-03T09:03:58.205327+00:00 app[web.1]:     import atom.data
2014-07-03T09:03:58.205364+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/data.py", line 24, in <module>
2014-07-03T09:03:58.205429+00:00 app[web.1]:     import atom.core
2014-07-03T09:03:58.205516+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named core
2014-07-03T09:03:59.454062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My first thought was to include gdata and atom in my requirements.txt (it looks like gdata depends on atom)

I tried adding this to my requirements.txt: gdata==2.0.18 atom==0.3.7. However I don't think I'm going about this the right away. The gdata-python-client I downloaded came with a setup.py file that I think I'm supposed to use when pushing to heroku, but I can't seem to get to work either (always get the same error above).

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Adding a package to requirements.txt will cause pip to install it, which it does by running the setup.py. But what happens when you use the requirements.txt locally (which you should be doing anyway)?

Comment: Also, what makes you think you need to install atom? That appears to be a completely unrelated project. The gdata client [includes a module called atom](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Fatom) which is presumably the one you need, so you shouldn't need to install anything else.

Comment: With my requirements file just including gdata==2.0.18 (took out atom), the app works fine locally. As soon as I push to Heroku, it keeps crashing with the above error. I just want to know if including gdata in requirements is the only thing I need to do here?

Comment: Yes, it's the only thing you need to do. Perhaps you should post the content of your message.py file, which is importing atom?

Comment: An easy solution is use an external importer, like [CloudSponge](http://cloudsponge.com). It's even available as a Heroku addon, and imports contacts from Linkedin, Facebook, Yahoo, Hotmail, MSN, Gmail, AOL, Outlook and Mac OS X Address Book. Take a look [here](http://blog.alistairrobinson.com/importing-contacts-with-cloudsponge-ember-js-and-django-rest-framework) to see it used with Django. **Disclaimer**: I work at CloudSponge.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have gotten around it, but the only way I could fix this error was by removing gdata from requirements.txt and including the /build and /atom folder from https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/ in my root directory.